# Jfrog Search & Delete Not Working

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang, jfrog-cli

I am trying to search for all files that are in my repo on Artifactory. I have Go installed, and am using Jfrog to query the search using:

```
jfrog rt s https://URL/artifactory/generic-sgca/
```

Which returns:

```
[Info] Searching artifacts...
[Info] Found 0 artifacts.
[]
```

Why is it not returning all folders in this repo? I believe my config is setup correctly too.

Comment: try:  jfrog rt s artifactory/generic-sgca/*

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to be specifying the `https://url/artifactory` when using search function in the CLI.

you can check the CLI's search help using `jfrog rt s -h` and you'll see that the usage is:

```
jfrog rt s [command options] <search pattern>
```

where search pattern should:

```
Specifies the search path in Artifactory, in the following format: <repository name>/<repository path>
```

The URL is actually a command option `--url=http://myurl:myport/artifactory`  which you can leave out if you use `jfrog rt config` to set the Artifactory server details before you run the search command.

You can read more and find some snippet example [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles)